# Illegal use of this type as an expression - VS 2012

Tags: c++

When compiling my source I got this error, **'MPageArrayCursor' : illegal use of this type as an expression** on this part of the source:

```
class MPageArrayCursor { 
protected: 
    int m_nIndex;

public: 
    MPageArrayCursor(int nIndex) { 
        m_nIndex = nIndex; 
    } 

    virtual ~MPageArrayCursor(); 

    int GetIndex() {
        return m_nIndex; 
    } 

    void SetIndex(int nIndex) {
        m_nIndex = nIndex;
    } 
};

void Add(T pData, MPageArrayCursor* pCursor=NULL)
{
    int nFreeSlot = m_UnusedQueue.top();
    m_UnusedQueue.pop();

    Set(nFreeSlot, pData, pCursor);
}
```

Originally was a VC++ 2k10 solution that I ported to 2k12.
Why I'm getting this error?

This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/xjVKCZjZ

Comment: is Add a template inline function?

Comment: Well what is `MPageArrayCursor`? What is `Set`? Make a testcase.

Comment: `class MPageArrayCursor {
protected:
 int  m_nIndex;
public:
 MPageArrayCursor(int nIndex) { m_nIndex = nIndex; }
 virtual ~MPageArrayCursor();
 int GetIndex()     { return m_nIndex; }
 void SetIndex(int nIndex)  { m_nIndex = nIndex; }
};`

Comment: With slight (seemingly irrelevant) modifications, [works on GCC 4.7.2](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=986ceac24f76df22051c719209ba2e37).

Comment: And again, your full code, with the include guard and `crtdbg.h` gone, works on GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: It would help if you included the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine except you need to include functional header for [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) function operator on VS2012

```
#include <functional>
```

Comment: OMG it works, mate! tyvm to you and all others that tried to help me.